# Criando getFullYear com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde galera. Veja se vocês conseguem me ajudar em algo.

Preciso gerar uma lista de dadas. Ano fabricação e Ano Modelo.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
var i;
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--)
{

  $('#ano_fabricacao').append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
  $('#ano_modelo').append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
}

$('#ano_fabricacao').change(function() {
  var ano = $(this).val();
  $('#ano_modelo').find('option').remove();
  $('#ano_modelo').append('<option value="">Até</option>');
  for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= ano; i--)
  {
    $('#ano_modelo').append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
  }
});
```

Ao seleciona o ano de fabricação, no ano do modelo aparece apenas os anos seguintes.
Exemplo: Selecionei 2018 na fabricação e no ano modelo aparece apenas, 2018, 2019 e 2020 que são os anos seguinte.
Quanto a isso tudo bem.
Mas gostaria de uma mudança. Ao selecionar o ano de 2015 (na fabricação) gostaria que apareça só 2015 e 2016 (no modelo). Seria apenas o ano seguinte.

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que vc se perdeu um pouco no código quando inseriu um **`for`** no evento **change** do `select` de ano de fabricação dificultando o controle dos anos, no exemplo que fiz abaixo eu nem o utilizei, apenas inseri no select de ano do modelo um `option` com o próprio ano selecionado e um outro `option` que pego o ano seguinte, bastando apenas pegar o ano selecionado fazendo a conversão para **Number** adicionando mais **`1`** e armazenando isto em uma variável:

```js
for (let i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
  $('#ano_fabricacao').append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
  $('#ano_modelo').append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
}

$('#ano_fabricacao').change(function() {
  var ano = $(this).val();
  var anoSeg = Number(ano) + 1;            // ano escolhido + 1

  $('#ano_modelo').find('option').remove();
  $('#ano_modelo').append('<option value="">Até</option>');

  $('#ano_modelo').append("<option value="+ano+">"+ano+"</option>");
  $('#ano_modelo').append("<option value="+anoSeg+">"+anoSeg+"</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ano_fabricacao">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
</select>

<select id="ano_modelo">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Verdade @LeAndrade não sei porque coloquei aquele outro for dentro do change. Mas Obrigado pela ajuda. Ajudou muito!

Comment: Legal que ajudou man, sucesso!